# Error when trying to add visible marks in vim

Tags: linux, vim, cygwin

I am trying to use visible markers in vim.
I have the following in my `.vimrc` file:

```
sign define information text=!> linehl=Warning texthl=Error  
exe ":sign place 123 line=" . line(.) ."name=information file=" . expand("%:p")  
map <F7> :exe ":sign place 123 line=" . line(".") ."name=information file=".expand("%:p")<CR>
```

But when I open vim I get an error in line `exe ":sign etc`

```
line   30:  
E15: Invalid expression: .) ."name=information file=" . expand("%:p")  
E116: Invalid arguments for function line(.) ."name=information file=" . expand("%:p")  
E15: Invalid expression: ":sign place 123 line=" . line(.) ."name=information file=" .   expand("%:p")
```

What is the problem with my syntax?

Comment: :s/visible marks/signs

Comment: @romainl:What is this command?

Comment: An inside joke and a comment: you should call them "signs" instead of "visible marks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is fairly easy to spot.

You wrote

```
line(.)
```

instead of

```
line('.') or line(".")
```

***edit***

The error message in your question was related to the error above but there's a second error, a missing space.

1. Your line:

   ```
   exe ":sign place 123 line=" . line(.) ."name=information file=" . expand("%:p")
   ```
2. First error corrected by putting the argument to `line()` in quotes (fixed `expand()` as well):

   ```
   exe ":sign place 123 line=" . line('.') ."name=information file=" . expand('%:p')
   ```
3. Second error corrected by adding a missing space after the third double quote:

   ```
   exe ":sign place 123 line=" . line('.') ." name=information file=" . expand('%:p')
                                             ^
                                             +-- added missing space
   ```

Because of the missing space, the value of the `line` argument was something like `26name=information` and the `name` argument was missing.

Comment: If I write:`exe ":sign place 123 line=" . line('.') ."name=information file=" . expand("%:p")` I still get an error on this line about E474 Invalid argument

Comment: Same problem with `exe ":sign place 123 line=" . line(".") ."name=information file=" . expand("%:p")`

Comment: You need to use single quotes inside the surrounding double quotes: `:exe "echo 'This is line number " . line('.') . ". You bet it is.'"`. If you don't do that Vim will get lost trying to figure where the expression to execute ends.

Comment: This `exe ":sign place 123 line=' . line('.') .'name=information file=" . expand("%:p")` does not work either. I am not sure I understand which part you mean that should be corrected

Comment: Your command `echo` is straitforward.But in my case I am not sure which part should be in single quotes

Comment: @user65971, see my edit.

Comment: The `.` are appending like in `perl`? Also why did the expand needed single quotes? It was outside of double quotes

Comment: Actually, the quotes don't matter in this case, it's a legibility/convention issue. You may not care about that but I do. I'm not familiar with Perl but concatenation works pretty much like in PHP: `"abc" . "def"` produces `"abcdef"` while `"abc" . " def"` produces `"abc def"`.